# Having trouble with grid display css

Tags: css, css-grid

In my code, I am trying to display a wrapper element as a grid, but when I inspect the page, it is telling me that my display / grid-template-columns / grid-template-area are invalid inputs. I am confused as to why this is happening, can anyone take a look  at this and give me their input?

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--Linking our new CSS style sheet to flexform.php -->    
    <link href="./css/flex_nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Flex Nav</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

        <header class="header">    
            <h1>INF7440</h1>
        </header>

    <nav>

<!--Use of HTML tags give more semantic meaning to code -->
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">BGAles</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="item button"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li class="item button secondary"><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            <li class="toggle"><span class="bars"></span></li>
        </ul>


    </nav>



    <div id="wrapper">

        <aside class="aside-1">
            <h1>Aside 1</h1>
            <p>Pellentesque id ante quis lacus condimentum suscipit eu quis justo. Nam cursus sollicitudin tortor, ut porta orci placerat a.</p>
        </aside>

        <article class="article">
            <h1>Article</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac sem dignissim, porttitor sem sed, eleifend dolor. Cras enim ex, rhoncus in euismod eget, placerat vel enim.</p>
        </article>

        <aside class="aside-2">
            <h1>Aside 2</h1>
            <p>Duis id lobortis sem. Pellentesque efficitur lacus nec condimentum auctor. Vivamus est purus, feugiat sit amet pellentesque et, semper quis lacus.</p>
        </aside>

        <aside class="aside-3">
            <h1>Aside 3</h1>
            <p>Fusce mattis leo augue, a cursus lorem elementum at. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </aside>

        <article class="article">
            <h1>Article 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac sem dignissim, porttitor sem sed, eleifend dolor. Cras enim ex, rhoncus in euismod eget, placerat vel enim.</p>
        </article>

        <aside class="aside-4">
            <h1>Aside 3</h1>
            <p>Etiam nec nisl quam. Nunc malesuada lectus urna, ut sagittis felis dapibus et. Aliquam augue purus, ultrices vel imperdiet et, interdum eu dui.</p>
        </aside>

        <article class="pct">
            <h1>family</h1>
            <section class="section-1">
                <div class="pct-image"><img src="./images/grandpa.jpg"></div>
            </section>
        </article>

        <footer class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li>This is</li>
                <li>A footer</li>
            </ul>
        </footer>

    </div>



    <!--Loading jquery library dynamically -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Adding additional jquery script to page -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
                if($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
                    $(".item").removeClass("active");
                } else {
                    $(".item").addClass("active");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

here is my css for the wrapper element

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 214);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                        "nav nav nav"
                        "aside-1 article aside-2"
                        "aside-3 article-2 aside-4"
                        "footer footer footer";
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the grid area to the children as well, e.g:

```css
#wrapper .footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

Otherwise they will simply fill the grid one by one.